# How to catch a tap on subview with negative position

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

After a day I give up. I can't find a way to resolve my problem.

I have a map with custom callout views which ones i would like to detect tap to go to another screen.

Look at my code, here is for my custom MKAnnotationView

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UICalloutView"])
    {
        for (UIView *subsubView in subview.subviews)
        {
            if ([subsubView class] == [UIImageView class])
            {
                UIImageView *imageView = ((UIImageView *)subsubView);
                [imageView removeFromSuperview];
            }
            else if ([subsubView class] == [UILabel class])
            {
                UILabel *labelView = ((UILabel *)subsubView);
                [labelView removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    MapAnnotation *ann = self.annotation;

    if(selected)
    {
        calloutView = [[AnnotationCalloutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-40, -50, 200, 30) andAnnotation:ann];        

        [self addSubview:calloutView];
        [self animateCalloutAppearance];
    }
    else
    {
        //Remove custom view
        [calloutView removeFromSuperview];
        [self setCalloutView:nil];
    }
}
```

And the result :

[image: Custom Callout]

The problem is like I have to use a negative Y position, the callout view is outside the annotation view, and tap are not detected. I've tried a lot of solution but none of them works great.

<s>My current solution is adding directly a view with a gesture recognizer on the pin superview, it works great but if the user zoom my view disappear.</s>

Please help me or i'm gonna kill myself ;)

<s>Edit : I Still haven't find a solution but now my view on pin superview does not disappear anymore when I pinch the map for zooming (I've add a Gesture Recognizer for intercept the pinch event). So it can be a solution, but definitively not a good one.</s>

**Edit 2 : Override hitTest on my custom annotation view is the solution. I can now detect tap on my callout subview.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding `-hitTest:withEvent:`.

Answer (score 0):

Need to know more about your solution for a custom callout to know where to place the recognisers and listen for them.

Are you using this solution for your custom callout?

https://github.com/j4n0/callout

If so just add a UITapGestureRecogniser to the CalloutView?  Or add a selector on the button on your calloutview xib file?  Not sure why you're struggling, are you adding these recognizers to the correct class?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your comment. No I not using this solution but i'm gonna look at it for seeing how callout interactions are made. My problem here is simple, when the user tap on a pin, I generate a view (my callout view) and I add it to my pin view. But for put my callout view at the good place I have to use a negative Y position, so my subview is out of the pin view and it's why my events are not detected, whatever solution I try. It's pretty hard to explain clearly.